# Component.find not working for lightning:input

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript-controller, component

I need to enable the text boxes based on the value selected in combobox -

Below Picture -
[image]

Based on the Combobox changed I am trying to enable the corresponding input boxes, which is not working  with component.find

Below Code --

```
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.contributionList}" 
            var="contriWrap">
                <tr>
                    <td><div class="slds-text-title slds- 
                      text-color_default slds-truncate"> 
                           {!contriWrap.classification}</div></td>
                    <td>
                        <!-- <lightning:select value="{!contriWrap.contributionType}" >   
                                         <option value="Fixed Dollars">Fixed Dollars</option>
                                         <option value="Percent">Percent</option>
                                        </lightning:select>-->
                        <lightning:combobox id="{!contriWrap.contribution}"
                                            value="{!contriWrap.contributionType}"
                                            onchange="{!c.handleChange}"
                                            options="{!v.contributionType}"
                                            placeholder="Not Applicable"
                                            variant="label-hidden"
                                            />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <lightning:input aura:id="{!contriWrap.contribution}" label="For Employee" type="currency" variant="label-hidden" placeholder="0" value="{!contriWrap.contributionEmployee}" disabled="true"/><!--<span class="slds-form-element__addon" id="fixed-text-addon-post">USD</span>-->
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <lightning:input aura:id="{!contriWrap.contribution}" label="For Dependent" type="currency" variant="label-hidden" placeholder="0" value="{!contriWrap.contributionDependent}" disabled="true"/><!--<span class="slds-form-element__addon" id="fixed-text-addon-post">%</span>-->
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>



handleChange: function (component, event) {
    // Get the string of the "value" attribute on the selected option
    var selectedOptionValue = event.getParam("value");
    var selectedId = event.getSource().get("v.id");
    console.log('Hi selectedOptionValue',selectedOptionValue);
    console.log('selectedId-->'+selectedId);
    var cmpTarget = component.find(selectedId);
    console.log(' cmpTarget'+cmpTarget);
    component.find(selectedId).set("v.disabled",false);
    console.log('after setting value');
    //component.set("v.seletedContributionType",selectedOptionValue);
},
```

Comment: You need `aura:id` to be able to use it with `component.find()`. In its current form, you have an `id` defined in your component.

Comment: It's aura:id on the lightning:input

Comment: Seems you are trying to find the id of the combo box on the handleChange event. In that case the id should be defined as `aura:id` on the combo box. Which component's id are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: I am trying to search lightning:input ..combobox id is used just as a search query. I want to disabled=false on lightning:input whenever it's  combobox changes.

Comment: You seem to have two component defined with same id. What is the error/issue you are getting? Adding those details will help.

Comment: well when I debug the component.find(selectedId) //this is aura:id of two components --  I get undefined ..and it's not working

Comment: Do you get value with `console.log('selectedId-->'+selectedId);`?

Comment: yes.. I get the value in selectedId

Answer (score 2):

`aura:id` cannot be dynamically created using `{!}` binding. [It has to be static.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm)

> aura:id doesn't support expressions. You can only assign literal
>   string values to aura:id.

So you can put everything between `tr` in separate child component and implement logic:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="contriWrap" type="Map" />
    <td>
        <div class="slds-text-title slds- 
                    text-color_default slds-truncate"> {!v.contriWrap.classification}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <!-- <lightning:select value="{!v.contriWrap.contributionType}" >   
                                          <option value="Fixed Dollars">Fixed Dollars</option>
                                          <option value="Percent">Percent</option>
                                         </lightning:select>-->
        <lightning:combobox id="{!v.contriWrap.contribution}"
                            value="{!v.contriWrap.contributionType}"
                            onchange="{!c.handleChange}"
                            options="{!v.contributionType}"
                            placeholder="Not Applicable"
                            variant="label-hidden" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <lightning:input aura:id="findable_id1" label="For Employee" type="currency"
                         variant="label-hidden" placeholder="0"
                         value="{!v.contriWrap.contributionEmployee}" disabled="true" />
        <!--<span class="slds-form-element__addon" id="fixed-text-addon-post">USD</span>-->
    </td>
    <td>
        <lightning:input aura:id="findable_id2" label="For Dependent" type="currency"
                         variant="label-hidden" placeholder="0"
                         value="{!v.contriWrap.contributionDependent}" disabled="true" />
        <!--<span class="slds-form-element__addon" id="fixed-text-addon-post">%</span>-->
    </td>
</aura:component>
```

and in parent:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.contributionList}"
                var="contriWrap">
    <tr>
        <c:childTdComp contriWrap={!contriWrap} />
    </tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

Also implement `handleChange` in child component.